# Magento 1.9.2.2 Always Zero Tax

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, tax

I have a big issue with a clean installation of Magento 1.9.2.2. The Prices of Products in the Catalog an especially in the Cart do not have a Tax Price. The Tax is always showing 0,00 €. I'm not new to Magento I installed it many times and I've never had this problem before.

The Frontend is e.g. showing price at product detail page including Tax 43,00€ and excluding tax the same 43,00 €.

Anybody with a hint?

I tested all configurations. I use 19% Tax for the German Market.

Thank You for any Help.

Comment: I found a Solution, i have choosen a Customer Group in Tax Calculation which was not related to the Tax Class ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?